# JBoss Modules outside of JBoss AS

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I had first found a reference to JBoss Modules when I stumbled upon Ceylon language which uses JBoss Modules as its module system. Immediately I wanted to try this system in some toy project and maybe even embed it in a real project (I was writing a project with plugins support at that time), but I couldn't find any documentation on JBoss Modules as a standalone library. The only available documentation source seems to be [the official wiki](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Introduction), but it looks abandoned and unsupported. I couldn't even find Javadocs for it (except, maybe, [this](http://docs.jboss.org/osgi/jboss-osgi-1.0.0/apidocs/org/jboss/modules/package-summary.html), but it seems to be very old and not really related to JBoss Modules due to "osgi" presence in the link).

It seems that JBoss Modules are usable outside of JBoss AS because Ceylon language uses it, but lack of *almost any* documentation on the subject is disappointing.

So, here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to use JBoss Modules as a standalone library at all? Are there any artifacts in some public Maven repository?
2. If it is (and there are), is there any documentation on it? That wiki I have mentioned does not have, for example, any instructions on embedding JBoss Modules.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, then i would imagine that if you ask nicely on the Ceylon development mailing list - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ceylon-dev - someone there might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @TomAnderson, thank you, I guess I will do it if no one would answer.

Comment: why on the ceylon mailing list, when there's `#jboss-modules` at freenode.

Comment: @eis: Oh, i didn't know about that. That's also worth a try! The thing about asking the Ceylon people is that they may have a user's perspective on it, which is sometimes more useful than a developer's perspective to another user. Although i suspect that some of the Ceylon developers are also JBoss Modules developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to try out JBoss Modules directly, you can grab the dependencies from the JBoss Nexus repository: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/jboss/modules/jboss-modules/

Unfortunately, there isn't much documentation on JBoss Modules, but if you want to try it out, you probably don't want to be hand-writing modules.xml files yourself (maybe you like pain, I don't know.)

If you'd like to try out "Furnace" the modular container based on JBoss Modules and Maven that serves as the core module system for [JBoss Forge](http://forge.jboss.org), it give you the ability to write Maven projects that can be loaded directly as Modules. This is what we are using for our entire Forge 2 architecture.

You can find some docs on Furnace here:

https://github.com/forge/furnace#furnace
https://github.com/forge/core#developing-an-addon

Note that Furnace Addons require a maven classifier, you can choose the classifier used if you want to. This is done via the Furnace Manager (which can be seen in the furnace docs above.)

Comment: Thank you, Furnace definitely looks promising. But it seems that it is not as dynamic, as, say, OSGi. Since modules are defined in Maven, adding a new module will require rebuilding main application. Or maybe I'm wrong? Also, why writing `modules.xml` is painful? IIUC, it is module descriptor and it is required to link modules with their dependencies.

Comment: You don't need to rebuild the main application to load new modules. You just need to disable/(re)install/enable and the module container will re-load any modules necessary in order to perform the module hot-swap. Is this what you mean? The example I demonstrated is actually showing this working, but only the installation piece.

Comment: And actually, maven is only one method of deploying modules to Furnace. You can do a normal file copy if you want, you'll just need to edit the registry/installed.xml file to get Furnace (which is monitoring for file changes) to pick up the change from the filesystem.

Comment: Just to note: the benefit of OSGi is the runtime dependency injection without reloading the container, so that is more dynamic than any other solution mentioned here.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. I guess Furnace is something which suits my needs. At least I can try to find out how JBoss Modules works in a real project. Thanks!

Comment: @els, actually Furnace can do that too :) That's what we call a reverse service injection. Just \@Inject Imported<MyServiceType> myServices; (which allows you to get 1, or iterate all currently available services of that type)

Comment: I don't think OSGi is that complicated, it's just needlessly complicated to use :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes. Actually, JBoss is using it that way as well - so JBoss application server is actually running inside JBoss Modules system.
2. I'm not aware of such documentation, but usually you shouldn't be embedding jboss modules, but running the applications with it. I'm not aware if you can embed it.

I actually got most information from this presentation in vimeo, [Modular Class Loading with JBoss Modules](http://vimeo.com/32211344). There seems to also be [Zen of Modules](http://vimeo.com/32214153) video there.

Comment: "but usually you shouldn't be embedding jboss modules" that's exactly the consequence of the lack of documentation. I thought that it is a kind of library, not something like OSGi container. In this case plugin-based application will have different architecture than if it was a library.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev yes, agreed.

Comment: Well, I was misleading about the "running inside it" part, it may be more worthwhile to think it as a bootstrapper rather than container. Still, it's not just some library, but the startup entity. Check the video I linked.

Comment: Thank you, the videos seem to be very helpful. Guess they will do as a kind of documentation.

Comment: You can always use JBoss Modules as a Library, that's what we're doing in Furnace in order to define the container-provided modules (see approved answer) - In this case, you simply use it as a ClassLoader factory, but you have to define the modules in Java yourself. This works just fine: https://github.com/forge/furnace/blob/master/container/src/main/java/org/jboss/forge/furnace/impl/modules/providers/FurnaceContainerSpec.java

Comment: Ok, that's valuable information. So normal usage is using jboss modules as a bootstrapper, which JBoss also does. However, library usage is equally possible, if you want to use and possibly extend it programmatically.